# Flutter video_player shows blank video when passing in a file

Tags: flutter, dart, video-player

I've taken a file object which I received from the Flutter camera library. Then passed that file into the Flutter video_player controller. Something like this.

`_controller = VideoPlayerController.file(widget.video!);`

When I do that the video shows completely blank. If I include timestamps it does seem to know roughly the length of the video but nothing plays - no audio nothing. I've been able to get it to work just fine in the exact same file if I replace the call to .file with a call to .networkUrl and pass in a known working video. I would think that it should take a file object without too much issue.

I've also tried using a different library, Chewie. Although I wasn't expecting much considering is uses video_player under the hood. It also didn't work just as I expected but I wasn't sure what else to try.

There are no errors logged to the terminal.

Edit to add more code context:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:loading_animation_widget/loading_animation_widget.dart';
import 'package:revvy/utils/getEnv.dart';
import 'package:revvy/utils/styles.dart';
import 'package:revvy/utils/svgs.dart';
import 'package:revvy/widgets/BouncingButton.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:visibility_detector/visibility_detector.dart';

final String S3_BASE_URL = getEnv('S3_BASE_URL');

class VideoPlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final File? video;
  final String videoKey;
  final bool displayProgress;
  final bool tapToPlay;
  const VideoPlayerWidget({Key? key, this.video, this.videoKey = '', this.displayProgress = false, this.tapToPlay = false}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  VideoPlayerWidgetState createState() => VideoPlayerWidgetState();
}

class VideoPlayerWidgetState extends State<VideoPlayerWidget> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
  double volume = 0;
  double prevVisibleFraction = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.video == null) {
      String url = '$S3_BASE_URL/${widget.videoKey}';
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
      _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(uri);
    } else {
      _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(widget.video!);
    }

    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

    _controller.setVolume(1);
    _controller.setLooping(true);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void setState(VoidCallback fn) {
    if (mounted) {
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final query = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final double width = query.size.width;
    final double height = query.size.height;

    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return Stack(
              children: [
                ClipRect(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  child: SizedBox.expand(
                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: _controller.value.size.width,
                        height: _controller.value.size.height,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            if (widget.tapToPlay) {
                              if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                                _controller.pause();
                              } else {
                                _controller.play();
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                        ),
                      )
                    )
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 132,
                  left: CONTENT_SPACING_3,
                  right: CONTENT_SPACING_3,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      if (!widget.tapToPlay) (
                        BouncingButton(
                          onPress: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                                _controller.pause();
                              } else {
                                _controller.play();
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: ICON_SIZE_LG,
                            height: ICON_SIZE_LG,
                            child: SvgPicture.string(_controller.value.isPlaying ? faPauseSolid : faPlaySolid, color: Colors.white)
                          ),
                        )
                      ) else (
                          const SizedBox()
                      ),
                      if (widget.displayProgress) (
                        SizedBox(
                          width: width - 200,
                          child: VideoProgressIndicator(
                            _controller,
                            allowScrubbing: true,
                          ),
                        )
                      ),
                      if (widget.displayProgress) (
                        ValueListenableBuilder(
                          valueListenable: _controller,
                          builder: (context, VideoPlayerValue value, child) {
                            final currentTime = value.position.toString();
                            final duration = _controller.value.duration.toString();

                            String formatVideoTime(time) {
                              final values = time.split(':');
                              return '0:' + values[2].split('.')[0];
                            }

                            return Text('${formatVideoTime(currentTime)}/${formatVideoTime(duration)}', style: const TextStyle(fontSize: FONT_SIZE_MD, color: Colors.white));
                          },
                        )
                      ),
                    ]
                  )
                ),
              ]
            );
          } else {
            // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
            // loading spinner.
            return Center(
              child: LoadingAnimationWidget.prograssiveDots(
                color: COLOR_PRIMARY,
                size: 64,
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the video player.

`_controller = VideoPlayerController.file(widget.video!))..initialize()`

Please look at the example code in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for answering but I did initialize it. I stated in the post that it worked perfectly fine with the call to .networkUrl and in both instances you would have to initialize it for it to work.

Comment: This code seems to have no issue. but i have a code which does the same thing and its works perfectly for me ill post it here. see it helps you anyways

Answer (score 0):

```
class MediaPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final MediaModel? mediaModelLocal;

  const MediaPlayer({Key? key, this.mediaModelLocal}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MediaPlayer> createState() => _MediaPlayerState();
}

class _MediaPlayerState extends State<MediaPlayer> {
  ChewieController? chewieController;
  late VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
  bool anErrorOccured = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeVideoPlayer();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> initializeVideoPlayer() async {
    try {
      late ImageProvider coverImage;
      if (widget.mediaModelLocal?.file is File) {
        videoPlayerController =
            VideoPlayerController.file(widget.mediaModelLocal!.file!);
        coverImage = FileImage(widget.mediaModelLocal!.thumbnailImage!);
      }

      if (widget.mediaModelLocal?.file is String) {
        videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
            Uri.parse(widget.mediaModelLocal!.file!));

        String thumbnailImage;
        if (widget.mediaModelLocal?.thumbnailImage != null &&
            widget.mediaModelLocal?.thumbnailImage is String) {
          thumbnailImage = widget.mediaModelLocal!.thumbnailImage!;
          thumbnailImage = thumbnailImage.getFullImagePath();
          coverImage = NetworkImage(thumbnailImage);
        }
      }

      await videoPlayerController.initialize();
      chewieController = ChewieController(
        showControls: true,
        deviceOrientationsOnEnterFullScreen: [
          DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
          DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
        ],
        allowFullScreen: true,
        videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
        autoPlay: false,
        looping: false,
        placeholder: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color(0XFF281E4F),
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              image: coverImage,
            ),
          ),
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        anErrorOccured = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    videoPlayerController.dispose();
    chewieController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  double radius = 8;
  Widget backgroundLayout({required Widget child}) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color(0XFF281E4F),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(radius))),
        child: Center(child: child));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var theme = Theme.of(context);
    TextStyle? textStyle =
        theme.textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13);
    if (anErrorOccured == true ||
        chewieController != null &&
            chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.hasError) {
      return backgroundLayout(
          child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.error_outline_outlined,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Failed to play video',
            style: textStyle,
          )
        ],
      ));
    }
    if (chewieController != null &&
        chewieController!.videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized) {
      return ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
        child: Chewie(
          controller: chewieController!,
        ),
      );
    }

    return backgroundLayout(
        child: const SystemCircularProgressIndicator(
      color: Colors.white,
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: see if this helps you

Comment: I have the same problem with this code snippet as well.

Comment: did you try on real device?

Comment: yeah. I know the file object is good too because I can resize it, then upload it to my api, then upload it to s3. And then when I render it with networkUrl that exact same video that didn't work as a file now works with networkUrl. I think video_player is broken. What version are you using?

Comment: I am on Flutter 3.13.4 and I'm using chewie: ^1.7.0. I'm using the same concept as you, uploading file to s3 and play them via URL. but I'm using AWS CloudFront to cache videos from S3 so it will be way faster when loading a videos via CloudFront URL. and the only permission I have on android is internet permission. I'm just giving these info, see it helps you